# Does the MSDN example usage of ReaderWriterLockSlim contain deadlock risk?

Tags: asp.net, thread-safety, deadlock, readerwriterlockslim

I'm using a ReaderWriterLockSlim to protect access to the cache on my ASP.NET application.
MSDN has examples of using the lock. However this article http://www.nobletech.co.uk/Articles/ReaderWriterLockMgr.aspx has me worried about deadlocks. Is this really a risk? Should the MSDN documentation mention this?

```
public string Read(int key)
{
    cacheLock.EnterReadLock();
    // What if thread abort happens here before getting into the try block?!
    try
    {
        return innerCache[key];
    }
    finally
    {
        cacheLock.ExitReadLock();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sorry, i miss read earlier,

Does this attribute not specify that?

```
[HostProtectionAttribute(SecurityAction.LinkDemand, MayLeakOnAbort = true)]
```

Comment: So do I need to compensate for potential aborts (in the context of my  ASP.NET app)? What is the safest way to do this?

Comment: The reference article you provided seems pretty solid. This article also extends the functionality http://vijay.screamingpens.com/archive/2008/08/08/readerwriterlockslim-extension-methods.aspx